# Determining selected option using jQuery after using get() to retrieve the select

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I have used get() to retrieve the first select drop down on the page like so:

```
styleSelect = jQuery('select').get(0);
```

And I can do normal things like

```
jQuery(styleSelect).remove();
```

To remove the select, but I'm having trouble finding the correct syntax to get the currently selected option's text.  I've tried:

```
jQuery(styleSelect, ':selected').text();
```

and several variations of this, I think I'm just missing something dumb here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use first the selector, then the context:

```
jQuery(':selected',styleSelect).text();
```

matchew's suggestion will work too but only when you didn't set the value-attributes of the `<option>`'s
(If you set the value-attributes you will get the value of the selected option instead of the text)

Answer (score 3):

```
jQuery('select').val()
```

should return the value of the currently selected element.

although, this does return the value. It is rare to return the text.

you could do it with something like the following:

```
jQuery('#test').change(function() {
    //get text(), change to .val() to get value
    var value = jQuery(':selected', this).text();
    //insert value
    jQuery('h2 span').html(value); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pCsF9/

**accompying html**

```
    <select name="test" id="test">
        <option value="AA">AA</option>
        <option value="MA">MA</option>
        <option value="LA">LA</option>
        <option value="GO">TEST</option>

    </select>

<h2>selected:<span></span> </h2>
```

*NOTE* change .text() to .val() and select the last option to see the difference between selecting the value and text. the `.text()` should return TEST, where `.val()` will return GO

Answer (score 2):

Here's the old-skool non-jQuery version that works in all scriptable browsers:

```
var option = styleSelect.options[styleSelect.selectedIndex];
alert("Value: " + option.value + ", text: " + option.text);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var styleSelect = $('select option:selected');
console.log(styleSelect.val());
```

Will give you the value of the option currently selected